# Why 'NoneType' is returned in Python?

Tags: python

I have a code that basically solves one of the problem in Project Euler and aims to find out LCM of first 20 natural numbers.

```
def GCD(a, b):              #Euclid's algorithim
    if (b == 0):
        return a
    else:
        GCD(b, a % b)

def LCM(a, b):             #LCM(a,b) = a*b/GCD(a,b)
    x = GCD(a, b)
    return ((a * b)/x)

def RFIND(a, b):
    if (b == 20):
        return a
    else:
        RFIND(LCM(a, b), b + 1)

print RFIND(2, 1)
```

But I face an error while running it.

```
    return ((a * b)/x)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

May I know Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
def GCD(a, b):              #Euclid's algorithim
    if (b == 0):
        return a
    else:
        return GCD(b, a % b)
```

You have to return the value returned by the recursive call.  `RFIND` has a similar problem.

Comment: Yeah that worked. But I somewhat cant visualize it, properly.

Comment: @Shub : What's happening is that you're making a recursive call to GCD but are not returning it, what happens is when that call gets resolved it returns void because of your else statement. In Python your method will return NoneType if it executes and returns nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You've implemented your recursion incorrectly.

```
def GCD(a, b):              #Euclid's algorithim
 ...
        return GCD(b, a % b)

def RFIND(a, b):
 ...
        return RFIND(LCM(a, b), b + 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not returning `NoneType`. It's returning `None`. The division says that it doesn't know how to divide the types `int` and `NoneType` as that is the types you are trying to divide. Try for example

```
>>> 'g'/6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

As you see it does't say it's can't divide 'g' and 6, it says it can't divide 'str' and 'int'. Hence:

```
>>> 1/None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

And as others here already pointed out, it returns `None` because you forgot the `return` statement.